# How to compute number of friends of friends in a BigQuery table with repeated records?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a BigQuery table with the following format:

| person | friends.name | friends.year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | Mary | 1977 |
|  | Mike | 1984 |
| Mary | John | 1980 |
| Mike | John | 1977 |
|  | Jane | 1971 |

I want to compute, for each `person`, the maximum year in a separate column, and also for each `friends` record I would like to get the number of friends that each of the friends has (which would be achieved either with a self join, or with a window function).

I am not sure how to write this query, my approach so far has been:

```
SELECT person, 
   ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT f.name, f.year FROM UNNEST (Friends) f), 
   ARRAY_LENGTH(friends) AS number_friends
FROM table
```

However, this does not compute the number of friends for each array struct value. This is the output I am expecting:

| person | friends.name | friends.year | friends.num_friends | max_year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Mary | 1977 | 1 | 1984 |
|  | Mike | 1984 | 2 |  |
| Mary | John | 1980 | 2 | 1980 |
| Mike | John | 1977 | 2 | 1977 |
|  | Jane | 1971 | 0 |  |

How can I write this query in an optimised way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
with friends_count as (
  select person, ifnull(num_friends, 0) num_friends from (
  select distinct name as person
  from your_table, unnest(friends)
  ) left join (
    select person, array_length(friends) num_friends
    from your_table
  ) using(person)
)
select person, array( 
    select as struct name, year, ifnull(num_friends, 0) num_friends
    from t.friends join friends_count on name = person
  ) friends,
  (select max(year) from t.friends) max_year
from your_table t
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]